# JQuery on click table button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, html-table

I have a table in which each tr has a button:

```
<td class='id'><input type='button' class='thisbutton' value='this'></td>
```

In the page, I would like to define an action for when there's a button click. So I tried this:

```
$('.thisbutton').click(function() {
    alert("A");
});
```

Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong. This is too simple for it not to work :-(

Comment: have you put this code in the dom ready handler ?

Comment: are you sure jQuery has been added successfully?

Comment: Check your console for errors

Comment: Provide jsfiddle for testing purposes. Problem is not clear.

Comment: JQuery is OK. I tried in the Dom ready handler as suggested, didn't change anything. No errors in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correctly include jquery, and this script, that should work just fine. As the comments have suggested, do check your console for errors as that will most likely give you a hint as to the problem. It's a core part of most script debugging.

Here's a doc showing how to use the console in chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

And the Firefox counterpart in case that helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/td4go6t9/

And the source for it;

Markup:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class='id'><input type='button' class='thisbutton' value='this'></input></td>
    <td class='id'><input type='button' class='thisbutton' value='this'></input></td>
    <td class='id'><input type='button' class='thisbutton' value='this'></input></td>
</tr>
```

Script:

```
    $(function(){
        $('.thisbutton').click(function() {
            alert("A");
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: I based what I did on another fiddle I found in reply to someone else who asked a similar question. And I saw that it worked fine in the fiddle.

As for what I'm doing, I have a search box which when the user enters a value, it does POST to a .php which replies back with a <table> in a <div> in the page. The table in question is located in that <div> which is populated only after a Search is returned.

Maybe it's because of this that the .click(function()..) doesn't want to trigger for the button click?

PS: Console shows 0 errors

Comment: If the response is appended to the DOM after the script is ran, the event listeners wont be bound to the new elements. Attach the event listeners again with the callback on that request and it will probably work fine.

Comment: Indeed, I just added a `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('.thisbutton').click(function() { alert('A'); });</script>";` after the php returns the table. And now I get a shiny A when I click a button. I imagine there's a way better way to accomplish what I just did with that echo though.

Comment: Would need much more information about it. How are you initiating that POST request? Would be helpful to provide a working example. If you're using ajax, a callback function is one option. See the complete handler on $.ajax for example: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: This is more than enough to continue by myself from this point. I will start by taking a look at the callback function and take it from there. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work, but I would check if you have jQuery correctly downloaded and sourced up top. Or if you are using a content delivery network make sure your url is correct.